Finding the point that a sequence of midpoints converges to
Question: Let $A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4$ be a square with $A_4=(0,0)$, $A_1=(0,1)$, $A_2=(1,1)$, and $A_3=(1,0)$. Points $A_n$ (for $n \geq 5$) are constructed such that $A_n$ is the midpoint of $\overline{A_{n-4} A_{n-3}}$. Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$.


My first observation was that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ is a point that none of the segments $\overline{A_n A_{n-1}}$ pass through.
Then, I tried letting $A_n=(p_n, q_n)$. Doing this, I figured out using the midpoints that $$2p_n=p_{n-4}+p_{n-3}$$ $$2q_n=q_{n-4}+q_{n-3}$$ with the initial conditions given by $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$. My first idea was to consider letting the limit of the sequences be $L$, but doing so yields $2L=L+L$, which isn't particularly helpful.
I then tried finding $A_n$ up to $n=10$ to find patterns with geometric series/vectors, but these efforts were largely fruitless.
I was able to solve the question by using generating functions as follows:
Let $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} p_n x^n$. Using the recursion $2p_n=p_{n-4}+p_{n-3}$, we have that $$(2-x^3-x^4)f(x)=2p_1 x+2p_2 x^2+2p_3 x^3+(2p_4-p_1)x^4$$ $$\implies f(x)=\frac{2x^2+2x^3}{2-x^3-x^4}$$ Decomposing with partial fractions, $$f(x)=\frac{-2(5x^2+8x+4)}{7(x^3+2x^2+2x+2)}-\frac{4}{7(x-1)}$$ yielding $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n=\frac{4}{7}$. By similar logic, $\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n=\frac{3}{7}$, yielding $\boxed{\left(\frac{4}{7}, \frac{3}{7} \right)}$ as the answer.

However, I am looking for a simpler solution to the question since the generating function solution isn't particularly satisfying. Any insight/hints would be greatly appreciated!

How would you approach the 1-D version of this problem, namely $A_1 = 0, A_2 = 1, 2A_{n+2} = A_{n+1} + A_n$?

@CalvinLin I solved the recurrence directly, giving me $A_n=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3} \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$ and thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n=\frac{2}{3}$.
However, I don't see how this was arrived at as the 1-D version of the problem since $A_1$ and $A_4$ have $x$-coordinates of $0$ whereas $A_2$ and $A_3$ have $x$-coordinates of $1$.

See Linear recurrence with constant coefficients. Granted, the characteristic polynomial$$p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)\left(2\lambda^3+2\lambda^2+2\lambda+1\right)$$has some messy roots.

@user170231 Can you elaborate on your point? Note that OP has solved the recurrence relation using generating functions. Does your factorization help arrive at the answer independently?

@CalvinLin Merely suggesting there are other ways to solve for $p_n$ besides the GF which may be less cumbersome

First, show that we can do this on a per-coordinate basis. Henceforth, we restrict to a single coordinate.
Let the limit be represented by $f(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$ for any starting real values.
Prove the following claims:
Claim: For any 4 starting values, the limit exists and is unique. So $f(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$ is well-defined.
Claim: $f(1, 1, 1, 1) = 1$.
Claim: $f(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4) = f(A_2, A_3, A_4, \frac{A_1+A_2}{2})$
Claim: $f(kA_1, kA_2, kA_3, kA_4) = kf(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$
Claim: $f(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4) = f(A_1, 0, 0, 0) + f(A_2, 0, 0, 0) + f(0, 0, A_3, 0) + f(0, 0, 0, A_4)$

 This might be the trickiest to rigorously prove, esp directly from the definition.
 It follows from the fact that this is true term-wise of linear recurrences, eg via generating functions, hence is true for the limit.

Claim: Hence,  $f(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4) = aA_1 + bA_2 + cA_3 + dA_4$.
Let $a = f(1, 0, 0, 0)$.
Then $ a = f(1, 0, 0, 0) = f(0, 0, 0, 1/2) = f(0, 0, 1/2, 0) = f(0, 1/2, 0, 0)$.
Hence, $f(0, 0, 0, 1) = 2a, f(0, 0, 1, 0) = 2a, f(0, 2, 0, 0) = 2a$.
So $1 = f(1, 1 ,1, 1) = 7a$, hence $ a = \frac{1}{7}, b = c = d = \frac{2}{7}$.
Corollary: Thus $f( (0, 1), (1, 1) , (1, 0), (0, 0) ) = (0 + \frac{2}{7} + \frac{2}{7} + 0 , \frac{1}{7} + \frac{2}{7}+0+0 ) = ( \frac{4}{7}, \frac{3}{7} ) $ as desired.

Note:

This approach easily generalizes to having $n$ starting points in $d$ dimensions and averaging the last $a$ values, where we just have to solve a linear system. In particular for $n=2, d=1, a = 2$, we have $f(1, 0) = \frac{1}{3}, f(0, 1) = \frac{2}{3}$ which is well-known.

I want to believe that this question already exists on MSE since it's such a natural extension of a well-known problem, but I only find the $n=2, d=1, a = 2$ when searching. As such, I posted this solution. Happy to remove if a duplicate exists.


